# Group by having count less than n or null should return true

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want this query to return 1 also in the case when no record exists. With a count less than 2 or even if no records exist it should return 1.

```
SELECT 1
FROM dbo.Product BS                       
WHERE BS.ASIN = '072142452X'
GROUP BY ASIN 
HAVING COUNT(1) < 2
```

The result should be 1 in the case when no record exists in the table.

List of All Products In table

```
Product

Id              ASIN                
1               12A
2               12B
3               1AC
4               123
5               12D
```

List of Accounts

```
Account
Id              Name
1               A
2               B
3               C
```

Now Listing happens in various accounts

List  of products Listed in various accounts (Product Id and Account combination is unique. Means one product will be listed in one account only once)

```
ProductListing
Id              ProductId               AccountId
1               2                       1
2               1                       1
3               4                       1
4               2                       2
5               4                       2
6               5                       3
```

I want if a product is already listed in one account or in two different accounts it should not come in my query of listing product

Query of Listing product in Account 3. So products which are already listed in 3 and in more than 2 accounts should not come

```
Select P.Id, P.ASIN
FROM dbo.Product P
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.ProductListing PL
    WHERE P.Id = PL.ProductId AND AccountId = 3
) AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.ProductListing PL                         
    WHERE P.Id = PL.ProductId 
    GROUP BY PL.ProductId 
    HAVING COUNT(1) < 2
)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, to cover both normal and edge cases.

Comment: Do you want `0` or `NULL` as the result when there is 2 or more records?

Comment: ... or no row? (when count >= 2)

Comment: Please keep in mind for the future that oversimplifying your scenario is not helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`CASE` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on the number of rows returned as follows.

```
DECLARE @Asin varchar(10) = '072142452X';

SELECT
    CASE WHEN (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM dbo.Product BS                          
        WHERE BS.[ASIN] = @Asin
    ) < 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

Note: there is no reason to `GROUP BY` when you are already filtering down to 1 `ASIN`.

Based on your edit you can modify your query to use the same sub-query as I have already show as follows:

```
SELECT P.Id, P.[ASIN]
FROM dbo.Product P
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.ProductListing PL
    WHERE PL.ProductId = P.Id AND AccountId = 3
) AND (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM dbo.ProductListing PL
    WHERE PL.ProductId = P.Id
) < 2;
```

Comment: This returns a row containing 1. I figured from the question that the preference was no row.

Comment: @RobFarley do you mean when count >= 2? When it returns 0? Guess thats why OP needs to clarify their question.

Comment: Yes - I meant 0. When count >= 2, your query returns 0. I thought the OP wanted no row.

Comment: I write this query inside Exists, so for 0 also  Exists will return true.  How can this return false to Exists statement

Comment: @Manjay_TBAG no idea... please ensure you provide a [MRE] when asking a question, because what you want is not clear as it stands.

Comment: That would be: `SELECT 1 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM dbo.Product BS WHERE BS.[ASIN] = @Asin) < 2`

Comment: @Manjay_TBAG I don't know why you are using `NOT EXISTS`? Just test the `COUNT` directly as I have shown.

Comment: You could combine the two subqueries: `HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN AccountId = 3 THEN 1 END) = 0 AND COUNT(*) < 2`

Answer (score 2):

Drop your `GROUP BY` line.

Consider how this will always give a row:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM dbo.Product BS                          
WHERE  BS.ASIN = '072142452X'
```

But `GROUP BY` means you return a row per group, and you don't have any groups because you're filtering out the rows that would've made one.

So this is what you want.

```
SELECT 1 
FROM dbo.Product BS                          
WHERE  BS.ASIN = '072142452X'
Having Count(1) < 2
```

ADDENDUM: I wrote it this way because it's the closest to the OP's original form. But another option, which doesn't get caught up in the nuances of GROUP BY and HAVING is:

```
SELECT 1 
WHERE (
        SELECT COUNT(1) 
        FROM dbo.Product BS 
        WHERE BS.[ASIN] = '072142452X'
      ) < 2
```

Comment: Sure it will. If COUNT(1) is 0 or 1, it will return the value 1. If there are 2 or more, it will return no rows.

Comment: @DaleK - the HAVING clause means that the overall query is an aggregate. It doesn't have to have an aggregate in the SELECT clause - the HAVING clause will handle this already. So then the HAVING clause either filters out the single group or keeps it in. And the logic for keeping it is COUNT(1) < 2.

Comment: Yip, I got that - thanks :)

Comment: My answer still holds. Just remove your GROUP BY.